# Can you obtain an unique identifier for a MATLAB object?

Tags: matlab, oop, uniqueidentifier

I am debugging some MATLAB code, and want to make sure that two references to an object are actually referring to the same object. Is there a way to obtain a unique identifier for the objects (such as a memory address)?

As far as I know I am not able to add my own IDs to the objects, as they are MATLAB random number streams.

Comment: are you using MATLAB's `RandStream`? if so it is already a handle-class, and inherits the equality `==` operator (`eq`). The rule is when comparing handle objects, use `eq` operator to test whether objects are the same handle. Use `isequal` to test if objects have equal property values, even if those objects are different handles. Ignoring reference semantics, you could compare the algorithm, seed, and internal state of two random number streams.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using OOP then you could add a property `ID` and set it during the construction of the object.

`java.rmi.server.UID()` is a nice way to obtain unique ID's

However testing by `==` will check the actual handles, so this is more of a usability issue.

```
classdef yourClass < handle

properties    
    ID
end

methods
    function obj = yourClass()
        obj.ID = java.rmi.server.UID();
    end

end

end
```

It will then be rather simple to check your objects.

Answer (score 5):

If the objects you're wanting to compare are MATLAB random number streams (i.e. they are of class `RandStream`), then they are handle objects. In that case you don't need unique IDs: if you compare them using `eq` or `==` and they are equal, then they are the same object.

As you say, you are not able to add your own properties to an object of class `RandStream`, but if you really wanted to you could subclass `RandStream` and add a property of your own to the subclass. You could store a unique identifier in the property, generated with `char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID)`.

Comment: I cannot easily compare the references because they live in different parts of the code. Seems like either I have to add code to be able to do the comparison or I have to subclass RandStream. (I was hoping for an easier/quicker solution.)

Comment: I would guess there's probably an easier way than that. For example, you could run the code through in debug mode, stopping at each of two points where you have the two references you wish to compare. Then save them off to the base workspace with `assignin('base',...)`. Then quit the debugger, and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UserData` field, which is present in every graphical object, to store a unique identity generated by you. If working with a user-defined class, you can add a similar field in your class.

The identities can  be kept unique by using a global counter to assign each new identity.

Comment: `UserData` is not at all present in every object. It is present in all Handle Graphics objects, but that's not what the OP asked about.